# How can I locate Registry key for Group policy settings?

Tags: powershell, group-policy, windows-server-2016, automation

How can I locate the registry entry for the below values

- Perform volume maintenance tasks
- Lock pages in memory

under `Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\User Rights Management` .

I tried the below 3 ways.

1. [Find the Registry key for corresponding Group Policy](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/38315-how-find-registry-key-corresponding-group-policy-setting.html) : (1)Final Link broken (2)Couldn't locate above in reference guide or MSDN doc.
2. [Which Registry Settings a Group Policy Object Modifies](https://www.howtogeek.com/115617/how-to-see-which-registry-settings-a-group-policy-object-modifies/) : No policy-related registry key located in Procmon
3. [How Settings are Stored](http://techgenix.com/group-policy-settings-part1/) : Nothing insightful in the .ini file.

End goal is to automate configuration thru Powershell [`Set-ItemProperty`]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the  [Group Policy Settings Reference Guide](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/group-policy-settings-reference-windows) (see your 1st link; in particular, [`Windows10andWindowsServer2016PolicySettings.xlsx` document](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250)), **most of security settings** (e.g. *User Rights*, *Password Policy*, *Audit Policy* etc.) ***are not registry keys***. Those are stored in the `Secedit.sdb` database.

For your task, you can use Microsoft's [`secedit` command line tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/secedit) (at least, export and import):

> ## secedit
>
> Configures and analyzes system security by comparing your current
>   configuration to specified security templates.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> secedit 
> [/analyze /db <database file name> /cfg <configuration file name> [/overwrite] /log <log file name> [/quiet]]
> [/configure /db <database file name> [/cfg <configuration filename>] [/overwrite] [/areas [securitypolicy | group_mgmt | user_rights | regkeys | filestore | services]] [/log <log file name>] [/quiet]]
> [/export /db <database file name> [/mergedpolicy] /cfg <configuration file name> [/areas [securitypolicy | group_mgmt | user_rights | regkeys | filestore | services]] [/log <log file name>]]
> [/generaterollback /db <database file name> /cfg <configuration file name> /rbk <rollback file name> [/log <log file name>] [/quiet]]
> [/import /db <database file name> /cfg <configuration file name> [/overwrite] [/areas [securitypolicy | group_mgmt | user_rights | regkeys | filestore | services]] [/log <log file name>] [/quiet]]
> [/validate <configuration file name>]
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> - Secedit:`analyze`   Allows you to analyze current systems settings against baseline settings that are stored in a database. The analysis
>     results are stored in a separate area of the database and can be
>     viewed in the Security Configuration and Analysis snap-in.
> - Secedit:`configure` Allows you to configure a system with security settings stored in a database.
> - **Secedit:`export`**    Allows you to export security settings stored in a database.
> - Secedit:`generaterollback`  Allows you to generate a rollback template with respect to a configuration template.
> - **Secedit:`import`**    Allows you to import a security template into a database so that the settings specified in the template can be applied
>     to a system or analyzed against a system.
> - Secedit:`validate`  Allows you to validate the syntax of a security template.

***Answer***: Look for the below keys/entries under `[Privilege Rights]` section in the exported configuration file (you can add/change them easy using Powershell):

- `SeLockMemoryPrivilege`    Lock pages in memory
- `SeManageVolumePrivilege` Perform volume maintenance tasks

Read (and follow) [**Windows Security Baselines**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-security-baselines) as well:

> A security baseline is a group of Microsoft-recommended configuration
>   settings that explains their security impact. These settings are based
>   on feedback from Microsoft security engineering teams, product groups,
>   partners, and customers.

Comment: Is there a way to read and write to `Secedit.sdb` using the `Get-PolicyFileEntry` cmdlet in the [PolicyFileEditor](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PolicyFileEditor/2.0.2) module?

Comment: `PolicyFileEditor` module = commands and DSC resource for modifying _Administrative Templates settings_ in local GPO `registry.pol` files. Nothing about `Secedit.sdb` afaik.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GPSearch resource to get corresponding keys: https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/

Also, you can try to apply the policy and track the changes in the registry with Process Monitor: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: The above policies don't show up on the GPSearch site probably since they aren't stored in the registry...

Answer (score 3):

While this answer isn't applicable for the policies specified in the question, I just wanted to throw https://admx.help in the ring for finding any registry keys relating to administrative templates policies. I prefer it over GPSearch mentioned by batistuta09 as it is much easier to read the information relating to the key/s, in my opinion.

To locate a desired key, scroll to and click on your OS of choice, then the policy categories trees for administrative templates we're all familiar with will appear on the right-hand side to be explored.

For example, I wanted to locate any keys associated with enabling the policy "Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair" locally on my Windows 10 machine (Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System). On the website home page, you navigate as follows:

Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 > Administrative Templates (Computers) > System > Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair

Once the policy is selected, any associated keys and their details are displayed clearly.

**2022 edit:** Updated url from getadmx.com to admx.help. Thanks, @Henke.